# JS method HTMLElement.click() stops working in Vue app after a while

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a Google Drive clone project in Vue JS using composition API with script setup.

I have a link tag in a Bootstrap dropdown menu like so :

```
<a 
   href="#" 
   class="dropdown-item align-items-baseline"
   @click="pickFile" 
>
    <i class="fas fa-file-import"></i>
    <span class="ml-3">Import file</span>
</a>
```

and a hidden file input like so :

```
<input
    style="display: none;"
    type="file"
    ref="fileInput"
    @change="onFilePicked" 
/>
```

When clicking on the the dropdown item, the user triggers the method below:

```
function pickFile() {
    try {
        fileInput.value.click();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

which simulate a click on the file input ref opening the browser's file picker. Then I have some code to upload the file in my `onFilePicked()` method.

All this works totally fine when the app starts. But somehow, after a while and doing various other stuff in the app, it no longer works. My `pickFile()` method will still be called (I console logged some text in the method to make sure of that) but the `fileInput.value.click();` is either not called or doesn't work. I don't have my browser's file picker anymore. No errors in the console. Don't know how to debug that. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a few changes, check the below working snippet

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const fileInput = ref(); // Line to be checked
    function pickFile() {
     try {
      fileInput.value.click();
     } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
     }
    }
    function onFilePicked(fileTarget) { // Function to be checked
      console.log(fileTarget);
    }
    return { pickFile, fileInput, onFilePicked } // Line to be checked
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
<a 
 href="#" 
 class="dropdown-item align-items-baseline"
 @click="pickFile" 
 >
  <i class="fas fa-file-import"></i>
  <span class="ml-3">Import file</span>
 </a>
 <input
  style="display: none;"
  type="file"
  ref="fileInput"
  @change="onFilePicked"
 />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain me what is it that you changed? Or what is it that I did wrong ? Because my code works as well. It's just that after using the app for a while, most of my events seem to become unresponsive.

Comment: Since you haven't posted your entire script code, I ain't sure what you have missed. But with comparison I have marked a few lines as `// line to be checked`. Please check the editer answer

Comment: @SaladeDeFruits If the answer worked, please feel free to accept and upvote the answer

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer doesn't really help me. As I said, my code works fine too. My question is more about what could happen in a Vue app that make some methods or events stop working which is my problem. Imagine that the code that you provided stops working after a while and you have no errors in the console. How would you debug that?

Comment: I won't be able to explain unless you post your entire code as a snippet

Comment: I fixed my problem. What was really going on is that all links and form submits were down on the page + no errors in the console. I managed to isolate the problem to a specific component. I don't know what was wrong with that component (which was a multiselect receiving options as prop) but removing it totally fixed my issue. Thanks Amaarocks for your time